# How to change default COM object name Microsoft Web Browser

Tags: c#, winforms, com, webbrowser-control

I am using the Microsoft Web Browser COM in a winform, but it's `Name` property is grayed out and I can not change it. The default name is `axWebBrowser1` and to be honest it doesn't looks like a good name! Any idea how to change this name?

Comment: Do you use visual inheritance and axWebBrowser1 is declared in the base class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in your Designer.cs File you will see:

```
 private AxSHDocVw.AxWebBrowser axWebBrowser1;
```

You can change the name to what you want, I would make sure you use the rename option so that all references are changed.

```
private AxSHDocVw.AxWebBrowser WebBrowser;
```